# Is there program that creates a program that creates another program?

Tags: arrays, performance, function, metaprogramming, shared-memory

Let's say we have the main program, let's call him program 'M'. So 'M' is a program whose only function/method is to create an object/program called 'x'. And 'x' can only create another object/program called 'y'. Each 'y' can complete a simple task with the same rate and they can work together towards achieving the same goal.

Here's a codified algorithmic representation:

```
    M = main program;
    function(M) { create many object/class/program [x] until goal is achieved  }
    [x] = 2nd level programs;
    function([x]) { create many object/class/program [y] until goal is achieved }
    [y] = 3rd level programs;
    function([y]) { Do many simple tasks until goal is achieved }
```

The main purpose of program M is to finish a very big and long task in the shortest time possible using an increasingly number of y's.

The question is, can this type of program possibly exist? If so, what programming language/s can create it?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, can this type of program possibly exist?

Yes. And it does.

> If so, what programming language/s can create it?

Any that can output code to itself.
Or, at least, assembly code, that can output assembly code, that can output assembly code, etcetera ad infinitum.